# Wired connection not working in Fedora 21

Tags: internet

[image][image]My wired connection is not working , although is connect.

I have Win 8/Fedora 21 dual boot system. The wired connection is working fine inside Windows 8. I have enabled the wired connection in Fedora 21 and connecting displayed but internet does not work. as a result no page does not load. I did not have this problem

Comment: Post `ifconfig`output and `route`output, please. Did you change the configuration of the interface at some moment?

Comment: No. I do not change

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting a network connection one should always follow the same steps, in order. Check whether you can:

- ping the loopback address 127.0.0.1
- ping your own IP address
- ping a machine in the same LAN (if there are other machines)
- ping your gateway's IP address
- ping a machine out on the Internet.  Try both IP addresses and FQDNs e.g. `ping 104.16.116.182` and `ping unix.stackexchange.com`. If you can ping the IP but not the FQDN, your DNS settings in `/etc/resolv.conf` are wrong, and you have to add there the correct nameserver (you can add 8.8.8.8 which is Google's DNS and will work fine).

*(adapted from my answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234198/cant-connect-to-the-internet))*

Comment: WiFi internet works fine , But wired connection is not working.

Comment: DNS Server address is correct

Comment: ping from gateway`s IP address display host unreachable

Comment: Please, show the ping's output to your gateway and the `arp` command output. Have you other machine on the LAN that can ping the gateway correctly?

Comment: no , i do not have

Comment: my problem resolved by changing ipv4 from manual to DHCP